# Find and replace in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a large simulink model, where I have to change a variable (say from 'x' to 'y') at 500 places.

How to do it ?

I cannot find 'find & replace option in my simulink

Comment: Doesn't pressing ctrl-f give you the find (and replace) dialogue like it does within the regular edit window in the MATLAB IDE?

Comment: No. It does not give the option. ( I was expecting the same)

Comment: Has anyone found anything related to this ?